# EF6 - View Mapping Fails on Entity Change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, view, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm currently generating a view in an EF6 Code First Database.  I'm doing so via the seed method, where I drop the table for my entity, and then create the view via SQL.

The problem I'm running into is that if a column on the view changes, and I change it in the model, EF6 tries to alter the table (which no longer exists) when it updates the database.

What I'm looking for is a way to solve this.  My thinking was that I could fix this one of two ways.

First, with some "before migration" method, I could be able to drop the view and re-create the table so that it was there for ALTER when EF6 tries to do so.  I'm not sure if this functionality even exists, so there's a hangup there.

Second, by telling EF6 to ignore my view entity.  This works fine for creation, but it's breaking when EF6 tries to map navigation properties to my view.
This is the error I get:

```
The navigation property 'Children' is not a declared property on type 'MyView'. 
Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.
```

Preferably, I wouldn't have to move away from using DataAnnotations to do my EF6 configuration.  There's a fairly massive code base that would need to be re-written if we need to move to fluent API.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: why not removing (blanking in fact) the corresponding up() and down() methods in you migration.cs (in the migration directory)?

Comment: @tschmit007  The EF6 implementation we have implemented uses automatic migrations.  While I might be able to create the view initially in a custom migration, if the columns of the view ever change, the second custom migration won't run because the automatic migrations in between will try to alter the table directly.

Comment: if **automatic** migration is mandatory, I can't imagine how to achieve your goal.